# How can I increase the precision of fractional numbers

Tags: sql-server, precision

`select 'foo ' + str(1.0/3.0, 15, 12)` returns `foo  0.333333000000`. Is there a possibility to increase the decimal precision so that every digit after the decimal point is a `3`?

Comment: Don't expand to 12 decimals the result of the division, expand to 12 decimals the value to divide. select 'foo ' + str(1.0 as numeric(15,12)) / 3.0, 15, 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the accuracy of your input values. To quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when performing a division on a decimal the resulting precision is `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)` and the resulting scale is `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`.

In your expression, both `1.0` and `3.0` are a `decimal(2,1)`. This means your resulting precision is `2 - 1 + 1 + max(6, 1 + 2 + 1) = 2 + max(6,5) = 2 + 6 = 8`. For your scale, the result is `max(6, 1 + 2 + 1) = max(6,5) = 6`. Thus you're new datatype is a `decimal(8,6)`. This results in the expression `1.0 / 3.0 = 0.333333`.

You are then casting this value to a string, with a precision of `15` and a scale of `12`. `0.333333` as a `decimal(15,12)` is `0.333333000000`, as the precision has already been lost; SQL server doesn't remember that the value is technically `0.3~`.

Thus, to get the answer you want, you need to add more decimal places to your intial values. For example:

```
SELECT 'foo ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(decimal(15,12),1.000000/3.0000000));
```

or, use a conversion

```
SELECT 'foo ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(decimal(15,12),CONVERT(decimal(15,12),1.0)/3.0));
```

Any questions, please do ask.

Comment: "This means your resulting precision is `2 - 1 + 1 + max(6, 1 + 2 + 1) = 3 + max(6,5) = 3 + 6 = 9`"  --  Are you sure this is correct?  By my understanding this should be `8`?

Comment: @iamdave ha, yeah i editted the post earlier, must have hit the wrong key, thanks for checking.